# What are the various patterns that I could handle a Future[Option[user]]?

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have a method that returns a Future[Option[User]]

```
def insertUser(...): Future[Option[User]] = { ... }
```

In my controller I am currently doing this:

```
val futureUser = userService.insertUser(...)
```

What are the various patterns in Scala can I handle this future to return the Option[User] eventually?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to deal with a data structure where **monad** (`Future`) wrapping another **monad** (`Option`) is to use **Monad Transformer** (I'll assume that you are familiar with concepts of monad in general).

For example, we can make monad transformer `OptionT`:

```
final case class OptionT[F[_], A](run: F[Option[A]]) {
  def fold[X](some: A => X, none: => X)(implicit F: Functor[F]): F[X] = 
    F.map(run) {
      case None => none
      case Some(a) => some(a)
    }
}
```

Then, we can operate on inner monad (`Option`) like this:

```
val futureOption = OptionT(Future(Right("Yes")))

futureOption.fold(identity, "No") // Future[String]: Future("Yes")
```

As you can see, working on inner monad is straight-forward with monad transformer (`Future[Option[A]] => Future[A]`)

To answer your question though, to return `Option[User]` from `Future[Option[User]]`, you will inevitably need to **block** with something like `Await.result` and of course is hugely discouraged.

Within your application code in the context of web server, you'll never have to leave the context `Future` from the start (request received) to the end (response sent) by leveraging **monad transformers** like the above.

With regards to play framework, you can use `Action.async` method to pass `Future[A]` directly as response.

Comment: I have database calls that depend on other database calls.